# Memory cost of storing a Date object vs integer

Tags: javascript, performance, memory

I'm creating a web-based game with Node.js and I need to keep track of a number of timers for each player.  I'm deciding between storing date objects for each timer and storing an integer representing the number of loops and based on an estimate of the game loop speed.

Is the date object method efficient enough or is the efficiency gain of the other method worth less accuracy? The longer the timer the less accurate it becomes with the integer method.  The date method seems much more readable and maintainable, just wondering about scalability issues.

Example game loop:

```
player.action = () => {
  cooldown = new Date(Date.now() + 2000);
}

setInterval(() => {
  if (cooldown < Date.now())
    //do stuff
  }
}, 40);
```

vs

```
player.action = () => {
  cooldown = 50;
}

setInterval(() => {
  if (cooldown-- === 0)
    //do stuff
  }
}, 40);
```

Comment: Unless you're talking about millions of these things, it doesn't matter.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, you have to measure the performance. So, you need to investigate what might need to be instrumented and do that.

Comment: Even for the first case, you don't need a date. You can do `cooldown = new Date(Date.now() + 2000).valueOf()` which will just use the timestamp (so a number) and you don't even have to worry about a potential memory cost

Comment: @Axnyff in that case it would probably be even better to just do ```cooldown = Date.now() + 2000``` and never even call the Date constructor. This is the route I'll go.